# How to check whether another app is using camera in flutter?

Tags: flutter, camera

I'm trying to create an app which will look for when another app is trying to use camera and override it and choose a pic from gallery and forward it to that app. Can I do that with flutter? If yes then how can I implement it?

Answer (score -1):

No, that does not work. It does not make sense to change the behavior of apps apart from you own.